# How to map over a value iff it's distinct from None?

Tags: python, functional-programming, option-type

Is there a concise way how to map over a value if and only if it's not `None`? Something like

```
def fmapMaybe(f, v):
    if v is not None:
        f(v)
    else:
        None
```

**Update:** I'm looking for a way how to process values, if they're distinct from `None`, and keep `None` otherwise, with the semantic exactly as my `fmapMaybe`.

In the above code, `f` is an arbitrary 1-argument function and `v` is a value that should be passed to `f` iff it's distinct from `None`. There are no further restrictions on what `v` or `f` are.

To give a specific example: I want to get a string value from a dictionary and convert it to an integer, if it is found. So the result should be an integer, or `None`. Using the above function, I'd write:

```
fmapMaybe(int, os.environ.get('LINES'))
```

Is there a shorter, more concise way?

This is, as Don Stewart commented, analogous to `fmap` over the `Maybe` functor in Haskell, or `map` over `Option` in Scala. (And if we consider that `f` can also return `None`, it will be analogous to monadic `>>=` in Haskell and `flatMap` in Scala.)

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit. Your question seems quite vague and unanswerable at the moment. You haven't given enough information as to what is `f`, what is `v`, what is `mapMaybe` supposed to do?

Comment: Sorry, what is the problem exactly? `f(v) if v is not None else None`? Or do you want to filter out `None` first?

Comment: You're implementing `fmap` on the Maybe functor in Python?

Comment: How about `lambda f, v: None if v is None else f(v)`? mapMaybe is quite misleading. Perhaps you should call it fmapMaybe.

Comment: @nymk Good idea, corrected. Yes, this is what I'm trying to achieve, I'm just curious if python already has functions like that, or if I have to define them on my own.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't tell us what v is and what you want to do, this is the best I can come up with. If v is iterable:

```
result = [f(x) for x in v if x != None]
```

If v is a single value then your if condition sound OK to me.

Comment: I updated the question. I want to place no restrictions on `v`, so I don't assume that `v` is iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to what was already said in the comments:

```
fmapMaybe = lambda f,list : map(f,(i for i in list if i!=None))
```

Testing:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, None, 5, None, None, 8]
fmapMaybe( lambda x:x**2, x )
#[1, 4, 9, 25, 64]
```

Comment: This only works if `x` is a list, I don't want (and can't have) such a restriction.

Comment: If you are using `numpy` you should check for `np.nan` instead